# Can those without a physical body wield a Lantern Corps ring?

Tags: dc, comics, green-lantern

I was curious if having a *physical* body is necessary to wield a Lantern Corps ring. We’ve seen all sorts of people wield them; planets, animals, aliens, etc. But, could a ghost perhaps wield one?

Comment: There's also a sentient *city*; https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Ranx_(New_Earth)

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se] SE! Please consider [registering](/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827) to more features of the site. As an unregistered user, you can’t vote, and you’ll lose access to your account if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Once you lose access, you won’t be able to accept answers or edit posts (without requiring other users’ approval) that you made under the unregistered account. Registering an account is easy, and it will allow you to participate more fully in our community.

Comment: If the ***fiction writer*** wants a ***make-believe non-corporeal entity*** to do something, then obviously the ***make-believe non-corporeal entity*** will do what the ***fiction writer*** wants it to do.  (But that breaks continuity!!  LOL as if that's never stopped comic book writers...)

Answer (score 14):

There are several example of *bodiless* entities wielding Lantern Rings of various colours.

- **[Dkrtzy Rrr](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Dkrtzy_Rrr_(New_Earth))** is a sentient *mathematical formula*.

> [image]

- **[**Flodo Span**](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Flodo_Span_(New_Earth))** is a sentient *gaseous cloud.*

> [image]

- [GPaak](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Gpaak_(New_Earth)) is a sentient *liquid slime*

> [image]

- **[Deadman (AKA Boston Brand)](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Boston_Brand_(Prime_Earth))** is a ***ghost*** and wields a yellow ring as a member of the Sinestro Corps

> [image]